# How do you do an if statement on a value from a datacard in Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApp that displays a field from an entity which is two options, Yes or No. I want to add an icon to the PowerApp screen that will be an 'X' if the value is No or a checkmark if the value is Yes.

How do I use an if statement on the icon to check the datacardvalue to see if it is yes or no? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming:**

- The "field from an entity which is two options" is a Dropdown control named `ddEntity_1`:
- The Icon control is named `icn_1`

**Set the...:**

- `icn_1.Icon` property to

```
If(
    ddEntity_1.Selected.Value = "Yes", Icon.Check,
    ddEntity_1.Selected.Value = "No", Icon.Cancel
)
```

If the Entity field in question is a Textbox instead of a Dropdown, substitute `.Text` for `.Selected.Value` above.

Answer (score 0):

You can initially add two icons into PowerApp screen ,one for 'X' for No and other checkmark for Yes,say **Icon_NO** and **Icon_Yes** respectively.
In the **Icon_NO.Visible** you can set as below,ie if selected value is NO,Icon_No shows up

```
    If(dropdown.SelectedText.Value ="No",true,false)
```

and in **Icon_Yes.Visible** you can set as below,ie if selected value is Yes,Icon_Yes will show

```
    If(dropdown.SelectedText.Value="Yes",true,false)
```